# How do I fix a problem of a solution directory that is not found in GEKKO for optimization

Tags: gekko

This is about a programming model that is correct, because it sometimes gives solutions, but sometimes (even for simple optimization problems) I get a directory problem.

```
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()            
x = m.Var()            
y = m.Var()            
m.Equations([3*x+2*y==1, x+2*y==0])  
m.solve(disp=False)    
print(x.value,y.value)
```

The error message printed is:

```
Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpdwyu_skngk_model0\\options.json'
```

How could I fix this problem? I think it has nothing to do with the model,  it's a general problem.

Answer (score 0):

How often does this error occur? Gekko uses a temporary folder to store files in text format, transfer those files to a remote server for solution, and retrieve the solution from the server. If there is an intermittent Internet connection problem then I recommend that you use a local mode where it does not rely on an Internet connection. To use the local mode (available for MacOS, Raspberry Pi ARM Linux, Linux, and Windows), change the `remote` option to `False` as:

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
```

If you still get an error and can provide a reproducable bug report, please [submit a new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I m already using the local mode (m = GEKKO(remote=False)) but still have the error . The error occurs frequently. when I run the code and I have this error, if run it a second and a third time ... It works in n th time but, I dont now hat to do, so it works from te first time

Comment: Could you try to go back to remote=True? Also could you send the files to support@apmonitor.com or post them to the APMonitor discussion group (Google Group)?